# Kendo grid Column align based on column data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I wanted to set column align properties across all grids in my application based on the data.

Is there a way where I could align the columns to center if they are of type decimal/number 
and otherwise align left for all other types.

I do not have column schema's I will need to determine it before the data is being rendered.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `attributes` like :

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "someField",
    title: "Some Name",
    attributes: {
      "class": "table-cell",
      style: "text-align: center"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `template` field to determine the datatype and set a template for the column.

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { 
    title: "FieldName", 
    field: "Name", 
    template: '#=Getvalue(Name)#' 
    }
     ],
....
});


 function Getvalue(value) {

            if (//check datatype)
                return "<span style='text-align: right'>"+ value+"</span>";
                //or add a custom class
            else
                return value;
        }
```